# Website display issues depending on the computer

Tags: html, css, xhtml

using the same resolution on five different computers, the same browser (firefox 14.01), 1 of them is mac, 3 are running on ubuntu and the last one is on Windows 7.

All of the test were executed on a clean browser without any plugins...

We also tried to swap screen, and nothing is different, it the browser had the problem, it still have it.

Also, using firebug, I compared every elements and all of them are the same, except that my link () have 2 more pixels on 2 computer.

I tried on every browser (Opera, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE 7-8-9) and I don't have the problems when I don't have it on Firefox, but when I do, I do have the problem on every browser...

I have display issues of many html elements.

So here is my question : What could cause this?

**Here is my HTML Code :**

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <a style="margin-right: 10px;" href="#">
        <img alt="View" src="/statics/images/Form/view.png">
     </a>

    <a style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <img alt="Edit" src="/statics/images/Form/edit.png">
    </a>

    <a style="margin-right: 10px;" href="#" >
        <img alt="Delete" src="/statics/images/Form/delete.png">
    </a>
</td>
```

**Here is my CSS code for the a**

```
a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Here is the pics :**

When it is not working :
[image: Not Working]

When it is working : [image: Working]

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Thank you guys...

We found out that the  add a padding-top of 1 px (which we don't think it is our problem since it come from the width) depending on the computer it is seen on...

Comment: Does the problem occur after a reset? * { margin:0; padding:0; } would be the most rudimentary example.

Comment: We are resetting in a global file every html tags... The meyerweb reset method

Comment: i see you're using tables; why not putting the 3 buttons in 3 cells?

Comment: @vlzvl Tables aren't made for design, but for information...

Comment: You have no `href` in your second `a`, and you are styling your links twice. You should remove the style from your HTML markup and keep the CSS only. Also, try to set `text-decoration: none;`

Comment: @morgi doesn't change anything... +1 for the idea ;)

Comment: Looks like your table cell is collapsing and pushing the third element down. What else is in the table?

Comment: Can you set a width for the td?

Comment: @MikeRobinson It is the same server we are loading, simply on different computer

Comment: @davidpeterson The problem doesnt come from the width, more why is their 2 more pixels on the image height, depending on the computer.

Comment: @user66792 That's not what I mean. The HTML table cell is wrapping the elements. The browser is making a best guess attempt at rendering your table, so I'm guessing that other elements in the table are pushing it over.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It is the same data on the exact same page, on a static design not a dynamic one.

Comment: So, what else do you have in this `table`? Full code would help here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your `a` as :

```
a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

td a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27px;
}
```

I put 27px as a width for simple testing, apply it according to the size of your images.

You can also try to apply a fixed width to your `td`, enough to nest your three images.

Comment: See the answer I wrote to @MikeRobinson

Answer (score 1):

Might as well just try this, then experiment with reducing the width:

```
<td style="text-align:center; width: 200px">
```

Since you're wrapping the image with a link, there's a chance you're giving it a border (this is for very old browsers, and shouldn't happen with css reset, but...)

```
a img { border: 0 }
```

Comment: Setting a width is only a quick fix, not the answer to my question, why does the image height have 2 more pixels depending on the computer it is seen?

Comment: @user66792 Updated with a random guess. Hard to debug someone else's browser, but the image border is a possibility.

Comment: yeah... sorry about that, but no, the image border is already reset, and I tried to overwrite it, but it doesn't work either... +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

a {

```
margin-right: 10px; 
text-decoration: none;
```

}

a:hover {

```
margin-right: 10px; 
text-decoration: underline;
```

}

1. remove inline style tag
2. add href to all tags better use javascript:void() or javascript:; instead of #

Comment: We removed the text decoration a long time ago from the comment of @morgi

Comment: Also, displaying my <a /> as a block would simply put the three of them on a different line...